# how to use FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); and where to implement this function?

Tags: android

can anyone help me with that? i couldn't build a app with this functions i can't find perfect resources for this.

What classes / components do I need to build an android app?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this line in the Application class as below,

   ```
   public class MApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Mention the above application name in the manifest
3. Add the dependencies as below in the build.gradle file,

   ```
   dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
   ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this anywhere anytime, but better approach is to use in your first launching activity, before referencing to any node at Firebase DB.